# Web Method doesn't reached in IIS

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, iis

I have Ajax call for a Web Method on aspx and in VS it works perfectly fine but when I'm putting it on the IIS(Which i don't have direct access to, I just put the files of the Website in the directory) for some reason the Web Method doesn't execute what it needs to do and it reach the success in the ajax and it return to the data(not data.d) the content of the page server.aspx

here is the ajax call

```
var data = { name: name, company: company, country: country, email: email, msg: Msg };
    $.ajax({
        url: "Server.aspx/sendEmail",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data) {
            //code
        },
        error: function (a,b) {
            //code
        }
    });
```

and here is the Web Method

```
[WebMethod]
public static string sendEmail(string name, string company, string country, string email, string msg)
{
   //code
}
```

Comment: What does the information given to the `error` handler tell you? Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: I said in the question(I will make it more clear) It reach the success in the ajax and it return to the data(not data.d) the content of the page server.aspx

Comment: Ok, so what is the `data` that's returned. My original point remains - what debugging attempts have you made?

Comment: data return the content of the aspx page the mehod is in. I have checked and there is no error message in it. the page itself is empty as well because i have only created him for the web method

Comment: `data return the content of the aspx page the mehod is in` do you mean that it's returning the code of the page?

Comment: Yes. The HTML part

Comment: In that case it sounds like your server isn't configured to execute ASP.Net code. I'd suggest talking to your hosting company

Comment: OK thanks. Do you have any idea what needs to be changed?

Comment: Not specifically, as it would depend on the server config

Comment: May I have your Button code? In ASPX page how you've tackled button click?

Comment: this is from jquey ui dialog, not sure why it would be the cause but sure.
`buttons: {
            Send: function () { SendForm() }}
        ,`